# JSON Objects from an API combined with Google Maps - Homework

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I have a homework that is way too complex for a newbie. Will get into it right away:

1. In Android Studio get lots of JSON Objects(roughly 200+) via an url, and load them in a fashion that is similar of ListView and they should be clickable and next to them Google maps.
2. If clicked on google maps aptitude and latitude is provided in the JSON and I should be able to pinpoint their location and add a description.
3. Cache the API search results for offline viewing.

I have played around for days on Android Studio but there is always something that doesn't match from online tutorials such as software versions. Can you forwards me to useful resources or show me how to get started the right way?

The technology I should be using is not specified. My guess is between React Native or Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To display a list of items similar to a ListView I would use an adaptor, here is a good resource from a reputable source.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jS0buQyfJfs&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGfHj1lwxOq67zAJV3e1S9S
To parse JSON here is another resource that should help you understand JSON in Android. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53BsyxwSBJk